# Unable to access objects in req.body array from Mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

OrderSchema

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
        OrderDate : {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
        userid : {type : Number, ref:'User', default: '0'}, 
        totalPrice : {type : Number, default: '0'},
        totalQuantity : {type : Number, default: '0'},
        status : {type : Boolean, default: 'false'}, 
        items : [{
            _id : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Product'},
            quantity : {type : Number, default: '0'}
        }]
    })
```

on POSTing via POSTMAN , console.log(req.body) form Nodejs Server returns

```
{ totalPrice : '755',
totalQuantity: '12',
userid: '3423324242',
address: 'dsadsd',
items: '{'_id':'5528cfd2e70144e020cb6495', 'quantity':'1' },{'_id':'5528cfd2e70144e012ab6495','quantity':'5' },{'_id':'5528cfd2e70144e020bd6495', 'quantity':'435' },{'_id':'5528cfd2e12144e012ab6495','quantity':'3' }' }
```

First of all I'm not able to access any objects in items e.g. items[0] as it simply returns '{' maybe because it is treating it as an char array.
Second what I wanna do it create a new Order Instance and make some loop so as to push all the item objects into the items array of the OrderSchema.
So far only success I've got saving data in items array it I send it individually as _id and quantity and push it as

```
order.items.push({
'_id' : req.body._id,
'quantity' : req.body.quantity })
```

but using the above method I wont be able to push multiple item objects into the array as these items are objects sent from a shopping Cart.
So basically we want to create a new order and then push all these items in the items array

Comment: It looks like Postman isn't using `application/json` as content type when it's making the POST request, that's why all the values are strings.

Comment: I post using x-www-form-urlencoded @robertklep

Comment: In that case, you need to make sure that your body parser middleware is set to [extended syntax](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#extended), but still, Postman needs to support the extended syntax as well before your arrays are transferred properly; `application/json` is _probably_ easier, though.

Comment: @robertklep Already using it ,app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: In that case it seems that Postman isn't uploading in the extended format, or that you're feeding it incorrectly formatted data (I don't know Postman well enough to suggest how to make it work :-)

Comment: @robertklep I'm feeding exactly same data i've written above. why are the nested ones not sent as objects??

Comment: Because Postman seems to be using non-extended, urlencoded body data, which doesn't support nested data.

Comment: Can you try logging out what req.body contains?  Make sure you you are using bodyParse.json() as well.

Comment: @JeffSloyer I think I've already posted what req.body contains, yes I'm using bodyParser.json()